# how to SEARCH SUBJECT in IMAP with utf8

Tags: perl, imap

I use Perl Module **Net::IMAP::Simple::SSL** to connect to IMAP server and search some mail whose subject has a key word.

beacuse the Subject has UTF8 charactor, i cann't get any result when use :

```
$imap->search('SUBJECT "Aone2"');
```

which **"Aone2"** is a keyword , in mail's subject.

hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-ASCII characters have to be sent as [literals](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.3). Please be advised that unless your server supports [LITERAL+](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2088), you have to send them as synchronizing literals and wait for the server to acknowledge that via a [continuation request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.5). This is mandatory and there are IMAP servers out there which do not support unsynchronized literals.